# Where can I ask a question about birthday cakes for programmers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There used to be a very popular question on Stack Overflow called [Surprise for a programmer on Birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420689/surprise-for-a-programmer-on-birthday/), but it got deleted. It had a bunch of suggestions for humorous code snippets and other jokes to put on a programmer's birthday cake, and I was planning to post pictures of the cake I just made with inspiration from some of those suggestions. It seems obvious to me that posting something on Stack Overflow is just going to get deleted, but is there somewhere else in the network that it would fit? Perhaps [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)? The cooking site doesn't seem like a good fit because there's nothing particularly challenging or interesting in the actual cooking.

Just to be clear, I want to create a page with a question like, "What are some fun ideas for decorating a programmer's birthday cake?"

If you want to see the content of the old page, it's available on [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=2420689&format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&printer=false).

**Conclusion:**

Until [fun.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27342/fun-creative-and-witty-questions?referrer=rLsBU5fwLkhoISm-eq20RA2) is launched, it has no home here, so I posted it on [my blog](http://donkirkby.blogspot.com/2011/05/birthday-cakes-for-programmers.html).

Comment: Thanks for including the Stack Printer link. If you want to know if something will be acceptable on Programmers SE, though, you should probably ask on Meta Programmers, not here.

Comment: Good suggestion, @Popular, I have now [asked on Programmers' meta site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1569/4092). I also clarified this version of the question to be "is there a home somewhere?" rather than just "is programmers the home?"

Comment: For the record here, I don't think the question would be a good fit for Programmers and [explained my reasoning](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-a-question-about-birthday-cakes-for-programmers-welcome-here/1570#1570) in the post on Meta.Programmers.SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's only asking for advice about writing code for somebody's birthday. It could have been asked on chat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes)

Comment: *This* question, @Mari-LouA, isn't asking for birthday advice. It's asking whether there's somewhere in the network we can ask for birthday advice. Maybe the current answer is to ask in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, this kind of topic could be a good fit for chat.

Comment: Off topic, but your [github link in your profile](https://donkirkby.github.com/) is broken. (Giving 404)

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, I don't think that question would fit anywhere on the network at this time.

Of course the question is preserved for historical reasons in any of the creative commons mirrors of our data, and [our very own network data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) as well.

For rationale, see [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), but the TL;DR decision point is:

> Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

That's the crux of it.

Comment: I really don't see why a question which is **widely** popular and targeted at programmers cannot have **some** place on the stack exchange network (be it locked, on programmers or whatever).  A lot of people, (myself included), program because it is *fun*, not just because its a job, in fact most of the questions that I ask are for personal projects rather than for work.  Is it really so inappropriate that it needs to be purged, deleted and relegated to archives and 3rd party sites?

Comment: @kragen I know it seems harsh, but allowing it leads to a lot of "oh, you allowed this, so why can't I..." whining and de-facto broken windows. It can belong somewhere, but not here.

Comment: Maybe the promise of cake will motivate people to support [fun.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27342/fun-creative-and-witty-questions?referrer=rLsBU5fwLkhoISm-eq20RA2). If not, you can see photos on [my blog](http://donkirkby.blogspot.com/2011/05/birthday-cakes-for-programmers.html).