# Where do the [fun] posts get moved to?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

So I reviewed one of my team's code and spotted some Pokemon Exception Handling, so put that in my comments. The team were perplexed as to what this was. I invited them to explore SO to find the popular "what programming jargon did you coin?"...  But it is no more.

So I fully understand the position on keeping SO on-topic, so moving the article aside thereby preventing the 'LOL-fest' of other sites... But where did it go?

Web Search turns up http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html but this is incomplete.

Surely community-contributed content should be retained, even if clearly marked 'archived'..?

Comment: If you're specifically interested in that question, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122164/can-we-un-delete-new-programming-jargon-you-coined, particularly [Ben Lee's link to "stackprinter"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122164/can-we-un-delete-new-programming-jargon-you-coined#comment324451_122167).

Comment: They go to unicorn heaven

Comment: @Oded Now I'm curious what unicorn hell must be like, and what kinds of threads go there.

Comment: @Servy Unicorn hell is just unicorn heaven without the unicorns.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the post. In some cases, the powers that be do exactly what you're suggesting, except that they call it "locking for historical significance," not "archiving." See [the FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) for more info.

In the rest of the cases, they're just treated like regular deleted posts: visible only to users with 10k+ rep and not searchable to users with any amount of rep.

Comment: According to Google, there are [about 8890 such questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+%22question+exists+because+it+has+historical+significance%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: I would think many of those search results are questions like this one asking *about* questions with historical significant, rather questions that actually *are* historically significant.

Comment: [308](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+%22question+exists+because+it+has+historical+significance%22+-inurl%3Atagged+-inurl%3Achat&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), actually, since you're counting `/questions/tagged` and chat. But SO itself only reports [188](http://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=noticed), so that's probably an even more accurate number.

Comment: There's an `inurl` feature? That's handy. I did think 8890 seemed like a lot. Thanks for the update, @waiwai933!

Comment: @Servy that's why I excluded MSO from the search results. Irrelevant in the face of waiwai's comment, though.